# Get Sync failed Error when running Azure Data sync

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, data-synchronization, azure-data-sync

Firstly set up azure data sync and it running properly and also do proper synchronization for a while.

But after running more than one hour ,i got error like below.

> Sync failed with the exception "An unexpected error occurred 
>   when applying batch file C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\xxx\xxx.batch. 
>   See the inner exception for more details.
>   Inner exception: 
>   Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Is it because of my client my Sql server ? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thz in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the Data Sync Service was updated recently. you might want to download the latest agent here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27693